# difference between string object, and primitive string

Tags: javascript

my problem is described below with example
number-1:

```
 var myString = new String('foo');
```

if i use `console.log(myString);`
the output is `String { 0="f", 1="o", 2="o"}`

and number-2:

```
var myString = new String();
myString = "foo";
```

here `console.log(mystring);` prints just `foo`

here what is the difference between number-1 and number-2 ? why the ouput is different ?

Comment: `new String()` part in the second is redundant

Comment: Notice that in the number-2 you are overriding the first assignment.

Comment: One is an object, the other is a primitive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This statement:

```
var myString = new String('foo');
```

...creates a string **object** initialized with the characters `f`, `o`, and `o`.

This statement:

```
var myString = new String();
```

...creates a string object with no characters, but that doesn't matter because this statement:

```
myString = "foo";
```

...throws that string object away and replaces that variable's value with a new **primitive** string with those characters. The net result is exactly the same as:

```
var myString = "foo";
```

The reason the output from `console.log` is different is that the browser providing the `console.log` is trying to make it clear that one of them is an object and the other is a primitive.

Somewhat confusingly, JavaScript has both string *objects* and string *primitives*. (It also has number objects and number primitives.) There is almost never any reason to use `new String`, which creates a string object; just use the primitive (in your case, a literal) instead. Conversely, there are very good reasons *not* to use string objects, such as this:

```
console.log(new String("foo") === new String("foo")); // "false"
console.log(new String("foo")  == new String("foo")); // "false"
console.log("foo" === "foo");                         // "true"
```

Because string objects are objects, `==` and `===` compare object references, not the sequence of characters. While there may be some edge cases where that's what you want, 99.9% of the time, what you really want is to compare the values. The good news is that:

```
console.log("foo" == new String("foo")); // "true"
```

...but that won't be true if you use `===`, which doesn't do any type coercion.

---

You might ask:

> So if `var myString = "foo"` returns a primitive, not an object, how is it that `myString.toUpperCase()` and such work?

Good question: The answer is that the primitive is automatically promoted to an object so that we can make the function call. (In theory; in practice, implementations are smarter than that.)

Comment: "Somewhat confusingly" --- if you didn't have string objects - you wouldn't have `'str'.length` and other wrapper-related things working

Comment: @zerkms: While true, that's just a language mechanism. At the end of the day, 99.9% of the time, you can (and should) use primitives that get auto-promoted as necessary.

Comment: Good point, @zerkms, but maybe he's suggesting that they should all be objects automagically.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thank you sir.
 i am beginner in JS. i hv finished almost the basic things of JavaScript. but i dont understand how should i proceed. i m confused what and how can i improve my skill and feeling scattered. do u plz tell me a proper and structured way so that i can make myself better in javaScript. it will be helpful if u give suggestion. thank u again

Comment: @skipperkhan: No worries. I'm not sure I can, but it's well worth reading some good books on JavaScript (David Flanagan's *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* for instance), and reading some online material (perhaps including -- very much in the minor category -- [my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript)). One of the big things about JavaScript that may not be clear to you (based on the question) is that it's *loosely typed*. A variable is just a variable, it can contain anything, and it can contain different things (objects, numbers, ...) at different times.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand is by running these 2 statements

```
console.log(typeof 'foo'); // -> "string"

console.log(typeof new String('foo')); // -> "object"
```

Also the second statement you are reassigning myString to a "string" instead of String object

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(typeof s_prim); // Logs "string"
console.log(typeof s_obj);  // Logs "object"
```

The difference is subtle, especially because methods called on string primitives are wrapped by string object methods, so functionally they are close to the same.

As pointed out in the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), this may matter on eval() calls. Eval will return the object "2 + 2" if called on the string object, and 4 if called on the primitive.

Comment: +1 for the actual reference. It pretty much explains everythin there is to know.